# Not able to print values of array in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I am not able to print array values in swift. My code is:

```
var array = 1...10
println(array)
```

The result is:

```
VSs5Range (has 2 children)
```

But when I try to print the following array, it works:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
println(array)
```

Result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Why isn't the first one printing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained,

```
var array = 1...10
```

array, in this case, is a `Range` object, not an array
If you want to print its content do this (changed the name to something more suitable)

```
    var range = 1...10

    for value in range
    {
        println(value)
    }
```

Comment: how can i print current index inside the for loop ?

Comment: as explained, a range has only two values, a start and an end. It doesn't have any index. If you want to "simulate" simply add `var idx = 0` before the for, and `idx++` inside the for.

Answer (score 6):

The expression `1...10` returns a Range, not an Array. Internally, a Range stores two values (a start and an end); an Array, on he other hand, is a dynamic structure containing "n" values.

Comment: so how to print array values ?

Comment: @Manimurugan You did it well in your second example.

Comment: Le I want to print my First array ? cant i print ?

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan Just wanted to highlight that you used `1..10` where his example shows `1...10`

Comment: Your first variable is not an array. Is `Range`!

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan how can i print current index in my second example?